# Is it possible to put all output from show_sql in a separate file?

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j, orm

When developing or running a spring mvc app locally that uses hibernate, it would be nice if I could get the output of all sql to a separate file.

Is this possible?

I know there is a hibernate property show_sql but I believe that will just get jumbled together with all other log4j logging info, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `org.hibernate.SQL` category to `DEBUG` and use a specific appender for it.

#### See also

- [3.5. Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)

Comment: great, now I need to learn how to use a specific appender.  Man java is one config issue to another, will it end!? :)

Comment: @Blankman: Never :) Luckily, you'll find some samples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436276/configuring-hibernate-logging-using-log4j-xml-config-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332608/log4j-org-hibernate-type-doesnt-work.