# How to set spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql: false for specific "session.save(Entity)" in a java class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my java class, I have a `session.save()` statement which saves some thousand rows in the database at a time.
Now as the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql` is `true`, it shows each and every insert statement in the console. This buries all important logs on the console and also other important hibernate query statements.

Is it possible to stop logging for any `insert/save` statements? **OR**
Is it possible to stop particular `class` from logging? If yes then please show me a way. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it solves your problem entirely but you can, for example, log SQL statements to a separate file. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285041/is-it-possible-to-put-all-output-from-show-sql-in-a-separate-file)

Comment: This is not what I needed but yeah... This can be a solution for sure as there is no other solution available. Thanks.!!