# Compare Date Java to DateTime Column in database table using SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, datetime, date

I've got two `Date` Java objects which will be assigned to some variables in sql query (because I use Hibernate) in order to compare them with a `DateTime` type column to get rows with a specified time range, for example:

```
  WHERE event_date >= :startDate and event_date < :finishDate
```

I couldn't compare date to datetime directly so I thought of 2 possible solutions:

- Try to convert event_date field using a query to date field before the comparison.
- Or try to convert date java object to dateTime which I think might not be possible..

What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: "Or try to convert date java object to dateTime which I think might not be possible" - Look at java.sql.Date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have the problems because you use `setDate` (correct me if I'm wrong) and `setDate` method:

> Binds the date **(time is truncated)** of a given `Date` object to a named query parameter.

Use `setTimestamp` instead, which binds the **date and time** of a given `Date` object:

```
java.util.Date startDate = … ;
java.util.Date finishDate = … ;
Query query = session.createQuery("from YourTable where event_date >= :startDate and event_date < :finishDate");
query.setTimestamp("startDate", startDate);
query.setTimestamp("finishDate", finishDate);
```

p.s.: be sure to use `java.util.Date` object and **NOT** the `java.sql.Date` one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and you were right about me using setDate. I tried this method but the returned results still did not seem to be filtered.

Comment: yes I do use java.util.Date. This is an example how the final date is created with the current time:                              if(fDate != null){
// adjust final date
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(fDate);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
Date fDate2 = c.getTime();
q.setDate("fdate", fDate2);
     }

Comment: @Best Weird… This should work just fine. Can you pls enable logging of generated SQL queries (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2333173/648313 for details) to see what's happening there?